# How to play DLNA content in Totem (Video) app in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: gnome, video, totem, dlna

I'm trying to play DLNA content (from my Synology server) via the Totem app but it does not appear on the *Channels* tab (while VLC on the same PC is able to discover and play). It is the totem app that comes pre-installed. `totem-plugins` is pre-installed. I've also installed `grilo-plugins` to no avail either. The plugins config dialog only shows 'Python Console', 'Subtitles downloader' and 'IM state' (roughly translated).

Is there any way to make it work?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where are your files stored on the Synology NAS? In a simple shared folder or in the video share? This may be quite significant towards how you access the files such as by mounting the share so that it can be "seen" by the video app. {edit] your question accordingly. As an example, I have videos stored in the `video` share on my NAS which is automatically detected by my Samsung Smart TV whereas other videos in other than the `video` share are not but I can still access them from a mounted network folder or from `Files` which lists the share.

Comment: Yeah it's shared too as Samba, I used DLNA because it was simplest way for all TVS, phones/pcs etc so see the content without apps, I don't think TV's can access samba tho. But you are right the PC could use samba/NFS while other use DLNA